# predicting proper regular expression from seeing target string

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I want to know it is possible to predict proper regular expression by seeing several strings. For example, regex `^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$` will match `my-us3r_n4m3` and `^[a-z0-9_-]{6,18}$` match `myp4ssw0rd`. But after seeing `my-us3r_n4m3`, is it possible output `^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$` or `^[a-z0-9_-]{6,18}$`from seeing `myp4ssw0rd`.

I guess this would be stupid question, and I don't want to predict exact regular expression.

Anyone who has idea for this, pls let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: no, it's impossible since `.*` will also matches your password.

Answer (score 1):

[`Regexp::Assemble`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Assemble) will create regular expressions from strings. The more strings you give it, the more precise the regex it generates.

Comment: The input to Regexp::Assemble are regular expressions, not the strings that match.  You would have to do something like `$ra->add(quotemeta($matched))`.

Comment: @GuidoFlohr Of course. Strings are regular expressions too.

Comment: Regexp::Assemble expects strings with regular expression *semantics*.  If somebody uses "x++x" as the password, you have a regular expression that cannot match anything, and the system is broken.  And that is avoided by piping the strings through `quotemeta()` first.

Comment: In fact, the OP probably wants to do something like `$ra->add('^' . quotemeta($matched) . '$')` assuming that he wants to match the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is an infinite number of regular expressions that have matched your string.  Even simpler than `/.*/` is `//` which also matches everything.

Still, you can find a practical solution for your problem if you describe more precisely what your regular expression should look like.  For the type of regexes that you used in your example, the following will do the job:

```
my @strings = ('myp4ssw0rd', 'my-us3r_n4m3');

my %characters;
my ($min, $max) = map { length } $strings[0], $strings[0];

foreach my $string (@strings) {
    my $l = length $string;
    if ($l < $min) {
        $min = $l;
    } elsif ($l > $max) {
        $max = $l;
    }
    map { $characters{$_} = 1 } split //, $string;
}

my $range = join '', map { quotemeta $_ } keys %characters;
print "[$range]{$min,$max}\n";
```

But that is very generic.  It pretty much answers three questions:

- which characters were used in the passwords?
- what was the minimum length?
- what was the maximum length?

Not really rocket science but you can maybe use it as a starting point to a solution of the problem.

Comment: `//` in Perl will *not* match everything, because if a pattern is empty then the most recent successful pattern is used instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is defining what is "proper". If you simply mean well-formed, then as mentioned by someone else `.*` will match anything, end of story. Furthermore, there's an infinite number of other possible regular expressions that will match your string. The two constrains that you may want to place on your problem to get meaningful solution is:

1. The regular expression should match the given examples and nothing else
2. The regular expression should be simple ("parsimonious") in some way.

If you loosen the first requirement so that you accept approximate answers, the problem becomes a classic sequence classification problem. Then, one possible way to handle is to train a hidden markov model with a limited vocabulary (in terms of what is available in the language of regular expressions) and convert it to a regular expression.